# Replace newline with string in sed on mac

Tags: regex, macos, sed

In a file, I need to replace all newlines (not the escape sequence '\n', but the actual newline) with a string. All the questions I've found on SO have been the other way around; i.e. replacing a string with a literal newline. This is on a Mac.

I've tried the following

```
sed -i '' 's/\
/STOP/g' file.txt
```

But it gives me an "unterminated substitute pattern" error.

Comment: there is no newline on sed line because sed work line by line. You should load several line (N, h/H g/x, ...) to work with multiple line. Your sed action is correct, try maybe a double quote or `-e 's/\n/STOP`/g'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While it can be done using `sed` also but doing this with `awk` is much simpler:

```
awk -v ORS='STOP' '1' file
```

This changes output record separator to `STOP` instead of default `\n`.

**Update:** Here is a sed version to do same on OSX:

```
sed -i.bak -n -e 'H;${x;s/\n/STOP/g;p;}' file
```

Comment: This simply outputs the file onto the command line without changing the actual file. How do I save the edits to the file?

Comment: For awk you do: `awk -v ORS='STOP' '1' file > _tmp && mv _tmp file` and `sed` will do inline editing.

Comment: Cool! Can you quickly explain the sed version? I've never seen the `H;${x;` and `;p;}` used in sed before.

Comment: `-n` will suppress the default output. `H` - Append a newline character followed by the contents of the pattern space to the hold space. `x` - Swap the contents of the pattern and hold spaces. `g` - Replace the contents of the pattern space with the contents of the hold space. `p` - Write the pattern space to standard output. And `${...}` means execute that block at last line only.